# What is the Russian public's view on the US claims of interference in the 2016 US election?

Tags: united-states, election, russian-federation, public-opinion, propaganda

Does anyone know of any rigorous study of the Russian public view on what happened in the 2016 US Presidential election?

There is a wide consensus, in the US, that top members of the Russian Federation and its security forces engaged in propaganda through social networks in attempts to influence the public opinion in the US during the 2016 US Presidential election.

Is that opinion shared by the Russian public?  **I am not asking for pundit opinions.  Talking heads will always talk.**  I am asking about hard evidence which would provide a pulse of the public (e.g., opinion polls and such).

Comment: This could be the first time ever that opinion polls have been called *"hard evidence"*.

Comment: @agc well, scientific polls are one of the better indicators of general trends.  Purchasing trends are another.  I guess in the case of political realities, levels and trends in the consumption of pop culture could be a good indicator.  For example, how was Colbert's visit received in Russia?  Did the Russian's public think it was funny?  If the joke didn't land, that would also be telling.

Comment: Something like this http://www.pewglobal.org/2018/08/21/russians-say-their-government-did-not-try-to-influence-u-s-presidential-election/? I wonder though: if you ask just for polls - it's trivial to find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Russian see US as hypocritical and do not believe Russia meddled in US affairs

First of all, Russians generally [do not believe](http://www.pewglobal.org/2018/08/21/russians-say-their-government-did-not-try-to-influence-u-s-presidential-election/) that Russia interfered in US elections, and that Russia could at all influence US politics with some Facebook ads or whatever is current theory about Russian meddling.

Second, Russians firmly believe that US interferes in other countries businesses (including Russia) , "promotes democracy" to the point of using military power, and is a greatest threat to whole world .

Third, Russians see US as [selfish and aggressive](http://theconversation.com/3-charts-explain-how-russians-see-trump-and-us-99839) power that uses any excuse it could find to harm Russia .